# Neo4j Cypher db hits count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Profile ) 
WITH childD  
RETURN count(childD)
```

**Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 20003 total db hits in 14 ms**

[image]

and the second query:

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Profile) 
MATCH (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childDStat:JobableStatistic) 
WITH childD  
RETURN count(childD)
```

**Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 224367 total db hits in 68 ms.**

[image]

as you may see DB hits incresses from `20003` total db hits to `224367`.. But I have `one_2_one` relationship between `childD` and `childDStat` and 10k childD and 10K childDStat  for them. What am I doing wrong in my query and how to decrease DB hits?

Comment: It depends on your model? Do you need to check node labels or not... if you have one_2_one rels, you could skip checking node labels, which would probably lower db hits... also you could simply use the count store to count relationships instead of actually expanding them

Comment: I extensively use CONTAINS relationship for different nodes with other labels. Should I change the rel name for different cases? Also, could you please show an example with count store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple relationships types can help you optimize your queries, especially if you are only counting relationships and not doing anything else. What i've seen in practice is having really specific relationships like:

```
(dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[:DECISIONGROUP_HAS_PROFILE]->(childD:Profile )
```

So something like that. Then you can quickly count relationships by utilizing the relationship count store:

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})
WITH dg, size((dg)-[DECISIONGROUP_HAS_PROFILE]->()) AS c
RETURN sum(c) AS result
```

Take a look at: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fast-counts-using-the-count-store/
It seems they have added a few more Cypher options to access the count store, but anyway, count store is much more performant than expanding each relationship.

You can get creative with more "complex" queries and rewrite the

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Profile) 
MATCH (childD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childDStat:JobableStatistic) 
WITH childD  
RETURN count(childD)
```

into

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Profile)
WITH childD, size((childD)-[:CONTAINS]->()) AS count
RETURN sum(count) AS result
```

Notice that you are not checking the label of the node at the end of the relationship, so your model must ensure that is always correct.